# A way to know if element in array of struct is empty/NULL in C

Tags: arrays, c, file, struct, null

I would really appreciate help with this piece of code.

So I have defined a structure, and then an array of structures:

```
#define MAX_ITEMS  30
struct item{
    char itemName[30];
    int identification;
    float sale;
};
struct item itemArray[MAX_ITEMS];
```

Then I have a function which takes the index of the array structure and is supposed to delete that element, and update the new array without the deleted element to the local *.txt* file

```
printf("item's index please: ");
char input[30];
gets(input);
for (int i=input; i<MAX_ITEMS;i++){ 
    itemArray[i] = itemArray[i + 1];
}

FILE *fp
fp = fopen ("file.txt", "w");
int index = 0;
while(itemArray[index].itemName != ""){
fprintf(fp,"%s\n",itemArray[index].itemName);
fprintf(fp,"%d\n",itemArray[index].identification);
fprintf(fp,"%.2f\n",itemArray[index].sale);
index++;
}
fclose(fp);
```

So what I am **expecting:**
[image]

Instead, I get

[image]

Finishing after thousands of lines, like this:
[image]

I would appreciate any help!

Comment: Note:  `gets` is deprecated.  It is unsafe, and no new code should use it.  Use something like `fgets` instead.

Comment: ahh forgot about that, will do! Thanks a lot, btw, is fgets really similar to gets e.g. can I just add "f" in front of gets and it would work the same?

Comment: Also, something seems to have been deleted from `for (int i=input i<30;i++){ `  It is invalid syntax.

Comment: `int i = input;` should be `int i = atoi(input);`

Comment: yep, my bad, I wrongly copied the code, it should be updated now

Comment: `itemArray[i + 1]` will access outside the array when you get to the last `i`.

Comment: You can't use `!=` to compare strings. If you want to know if a string is empty or not, check the first byte to see if it's the null terminator.

Comment: But I don't see the point of that check. Where do you put an empty name into the array element after all the valid items?

Comment: Unrelated, @TomKarzes `gets` isn't deprecated; it **was** deprecated in C99.3. It was completely *removed* from the standard library in C11, and has been gone ever since. Any implementation still supplying it is doing so entirely out of the standard body.

Comment: I changed it to:   `while(strcmp(itemArray[y].name, "") != 0)` and now works flawlessly. Can't believe I spend all evening figuring this out despite my program containing dozens of strcmps functions, old habits never die    @Barmar I don't put it there, but isn't it there automatically when initializing the array?

Comment: @SamuelV. It depends -- is it a global array or an automatic array? Global and static variables are initialized to 0, auto variables aren't.

Comment: @WhozCraig truee, name == itemName,

Comment: @Barmar it is a global one

Comment: Just make sure you never use in the last element of the array, so there will always be an element with an empty name.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just use a variable that holds the number of valid items?

Comment: @Barmar that is what I am thinking, the issue is that I need the variable to be always saved somewhere externally (not in the program) One way is to put it as an integer on the first row in the file, but it would be hard to manipulate the lines then, or just create another txt file where only this number is stored. Do you think it is worht it doing since this seems to be working so far?

Comment: When you read the items from the file, you set it to the number of items that were read.

Comment: @Barmar another thing is that I can set the MAX limit to thousands and it will never get full, because as a school project, this won't have more than ten items you know

Comment: Why are you trying to find reasons to do it the wrong way when the right way is so simple?

Comment: fair enough, thanks mate for your help! :))